# how sharepoint lookup column store its values?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I was trying to create a custom field type similar to lookup column just mine is filtered lookup column.Its working fine but I wanted to implement the same functionality like lookup column does,by that I mean:

For e.g lookup column is having title of some list so it stores its value as

SPListiem.ID#;title....but it shows only title when we r selecting or editing value in it.

I am using listboxes and doing

listbox.Items.Add(title);

but how to get Id also and specially hidden from users like lookup column does....means I can do like this...
listbox.Items.Add(title+"#;" + SPListitem.ID)...

but I dont want this....

Any idea how to achieve this...

Answer (score 1):

## Your solution

Indeed, it stores value as LookupId;#LookupValue

1. Use SPFieldLookupValue (or SPFIeldLookupValueCollection for multiple lookups) constructor and then you get SPFieldLookupValue.LookupId and SPFieldLookupValue.LookupValue properties.
2. Then, to add items to ListBox with
   ID, use

   ```
   listbox.Items.Add(new ListItem(lookupValue.LookupValue, lookupValue.LookupId));
   ```

   then user will see LookupValue, but
   you will have a way to get
   coresponding ID.

## Already existing solution

By the way, there is already available [SharePoint filtered lookup field](http://filteredlookup.codeplex.com/) which you may use if you wish.